# unixODBC Driver Manager "Data source name not found" even though it's actually there - MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, unixodbc

I'm trying to set up an OBDC interface to two different MariaDB instances and I'm completely mystified by the fact that one works and the other doesn't.

One db ("platan") is running on a regular MariaDB installation on CentOS7 on 3306, whereas the other db ("tlex") is in a MariaDB instance inside a Docker container on the same OS and running on port 3301. I have to keep those two instances separate.

Both databases are reachable from the command line:

```
mysql -u mrtlex -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 -P3306 tlex
```

and

```
mysql -u platan -pPASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 -P3301 platan
```

let me connect without a hitch.

I have the MariaDB driver defined in odbcinst.ini:

```
[MariaDB]
Description = MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.0
Driver64 = /usr/local/lib64/libmaodbc.so
```

And I have two data sources defined in odbc.ini:

```
[tlex]
Description         = TLex dockerized
Driver              = MariaDB 
Database            = tlex
Server              = 127.0.0.1
Uid                 = mrtlex
Password            = PASSWORD
Port                = 3301

[platan]
Description         = MariaDB localdb
Driver              = MariaDB
Database            = platan
Server              = 127.0.0.1
Uid                 = platan
Password            = PASSWORD
Port                = 3306
```

odcbinst seems to recognize both datasources:

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# odbcinst -q -s
[tlex]
[platan]
```

Yet I can actually connect only to platan and not the tlex datasource:

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# iusql -v tlex
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# iusql -v platan
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. I can access both databases from the command line, both databases are set up the same way as ODBC datasources, both datasources as listed with `odbcinst -q -s` yet I can connect to only one of them through ODBC.

What could be the reason? How could I further troubleshoot this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a dockerized MariaDB to be accessible via ODBC, the container itself has to have unixODBC installed as well as the MariaDB ODBC driver and the data source file.